# Jensen Inequality in a graphical form

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, geometry, analysis

There is an easy example in the use of Jensen's inequality by using the convex function of x squared and the conventional dice.

So the idea is to roll the dice and the outcome would be the square of the number received on the rolled dice.

Using Jensen inequality, the payoff from playing the game is actually greater than the prediction of the next outcome or more specifically, the average of the function is greater than the function of the average.

**My question**: how can we put that example in an easy graphical way instead of a numerical proof?

Comment: I heard Prof. W.W. Sawyer say that a function is (strictly) convex iff its graph holds water.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet this is lovely :)

Comment: That was long ago.1968 or 1969. I'm glad you like it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet But what about functions with wiggles that ultimately go up, like $x^4 - x^2$. I think they would hold water, but are not convex.

Comment: @NickAlger.It was a casual remark, not a rigorous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I draw the graph of the convex function $f$ on the blackboard, and say that the distribution of $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ induces a distribution of $(X,f(X))$ on  the graph $\Gamma_f\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.  The barycenter of the latter is in the epigraph of $f$, and hence $E f(X) \ge f (EX)$. I use scribbly shading to indicate where the mass is distributed, first on the $x$ axis and then on $\Gamma_f$.  I plot the barycenter, and its vertical projection to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Gamma_f$.

The dice example fits in this scenario without any trouble.  After talking through it, I would immediately go to another similar example: a coin flip, the sum of two dice, etc.

I try to draw such a figure whenever I can: it often suggests things not immediately evident before drawing.

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that you can upload the image on your answer please?

Comment: Done.  It's crude.  If I were performing, as I talked the figure would get more and more cluttered.  The last thing I'd write would be the formulas, after I'd had my say about centroids, above the curve, etc etc.